Problem with Using FormControl in Angular and PrimeNG Radio Buttons
Problem Description
In my Angular project, I'm using PrimeNG's radio button component (p-radioButton) within my custom wrapper component (x-radio-button). This wrapper component implements the ControlValueAccessor interface.
Issue:
Everything works fine when using ngModel.
However, when I add a formControl, it correctly selects the default value, but when I select the other option, both radio buttons appear to be selected.
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { RadioButtonModule } from 'primeng/radiobutton';

@Component({
   selector: 'x-radio-button',
   standalone: true,
   imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, RadioButtonModule],
   templateUrl: './radio-button.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./radio-button.component.scss'],
   providers: [
       {
           provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
           useExisting: forwardRef(() => RadioButtonComponent),
           multi: true,
       },
   ],
})
export class RadioButtonComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
   @Input() name: string;
   @Input() value: any;
   @Input() label: string;
   @Input() inputId: string;
   @Output() select = new EventEmitter<any>();

   checked: boolean = false;

   public _internalValue: any;

   onChange = (value: any) => {};
   onTouched = () => {};

   // Value accessor interface
   writeValue(value: any): void {
       this._internalValue = value;
       this.checked = this._internalValue === this.value;
   }

   registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
       this.onChange = fn;
   }

   registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
       this.onTouched = fn;
   }

   setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
       // Implement if necessary for disabled state
   }

   onRadioChange(): void {
       this.checked = true;
       this.onChange(this.value);
       this.select.emit(this.value);
   }
}

<p-radioButton
    [name]="name"
    [value]="value"
    [(ngModel)]="_internalValue"
    [inputId]="inputId"
    (ngModelChange)="onRadioChange()">
</p-radioButton>

<label class="ml-2">{{ label }}</label>

Usage Scenario
<div>
   <x-radio-button
       [inputId]="'2'"
       [value]="'http'"
       formControlName="protocol">
   </x-radio-button>
   <x-radio-button
       [inputId]="'1'"
       [value]="'https'"
       formControlName="protocol">
   </x-radio-button>
</div>



this.parentForm.addControl(
   'protocol',
   new UntypedFormControl('http', Validators.required),
);

Expected Behavior
I expect only one of the radio buttons to be selected. When using the FormControl, I want the other button to automatically be disabled when one button is selected.
Help Needed
How can I fix this issue? I'm open to suggestions.
